# How to add generated code to type provider

Tags: f#, type-providers

I have F# function

```
generateCode params
```

that generates a code on F#(.fs file).
And I want to write Type Provider, that runs generateCode() and gives generated functions as provided.

For example, my function generated:

```
module Calc

open Operations
let Calculate a b = add a b
```

And i want to have Type Provider that provides such functionality:

```
type MyType = MyTypeProvider<args>
sum = MyType.Calculate a b
```

**UPD**
The main problem is to add generated code to assembly and then get function names.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, creating a type provider is not that simple. Rather than generating source code, type providers need to build an implementation of a certain interface and then produce F# *quotations* (which is a data structure representing source code - like LINQ expression trees).

For a good tutorial on implementing type providers, see Michael Newton's [Type Providers From the Ground Up](http://blog.mavnn.co.uk/type-providers-from-the-ground-up/) and a follow up [Type Providers From the First Floor](http://blog.mavnn.co.uk/type-providers-from-the-first-floor/).

Comment: I don't need a code generator, I need Type Provider, because it can run my function in a runtime, and provide generated functions.